# SelectedItem changes textblock variables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I want to get all the data from an Object used as `ObservableCollection` in a `ListView`. The `ListView` is working properly I want to when the Item is selected the information in a `TextBlock` (outside the `ListView`) to update with the info that the object as.

How can I do it? What I'm doing wrong?

So to the code:

```
<ListView 
   x:Name="dataGrid" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" 
   Height="586" 
   BorderThickness="0" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFriends,Mode=TwoWay}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="460">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Resources\Images\ic_status.png" Height="24" Width="18"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
               <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding name}"/>
               <StackPanel x:Name="RemoveItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastLocation, StringFormat='Location: {0}'}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding timestamp}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<StackPanel x:Name="AdditionItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Visible">
   <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="loc.country"/>
            <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="loc.area"/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify `SelectedItem` property in your binding:

```
<TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="SelectedItem.loc.country"/>
            <Binding ElementName="dataGrid" Path="SelectedItem.loc.area"/>
         </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
```